# Oracle nested select with defined rows

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    nvl(dd,'TOTAL') "Subject",
    SUM(cnt) "Count,
    SUM(pct) AS "%"
FROM
    (
SELECT
    dd,
    COUNT(1) cnt,
    round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1) ) OVER() * 100,2) AS pct
FROM
    student p,
    student_subject a
WHERE
    p.sId = a.sId
    AND student_type IN (
        '1',
        '2'
    )
    AND dd IN (
        'MATH',
        'SCIENCE',
        'HISTORY'
    )
    GROUP BY
    dd
ORDER BY
    1
)
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(dd)
ORDER BY
    1;
```

My Output should look like this:

```
Subject Count       %
MATH    33          23.2%
SCIENCE 24          11.46%
HISTORY 56          44.778%
TOTAL   113         85.4.2%
```

If a particular subject doesnt have data it should still provide the row with 0 values like below

```
Subject Count       %
MATH    33          23.20%
SCIENCE 0           0.00%
HISTORY 56          44.77%
TOTAL   113         85.42%
```

What I am getting rightnow is below with no SCIENCE row which is not desired ,

```
Subject Count       %
MATH    33          23.20%
HISTORY 56          44.77%
TOTAL   113         85.42%
```

What I did is I removed the dd IN clause "AND dd IN (
        'MATH',
        'SCIENCE',
        'HISTORY'
    )"
However I am not able to get to the another inner select to select the 3 subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the datamodel correctly when a student is not enrolled to a subject an entry for the subject wouldn't exist in student_subject table, which means the missing subject is not present in the deficit table as well. Hence technically it is not possible to join these two tables and report for a column value that doesn't exist in either of them.
Now to solve this,i use WITH clause to create another table to hold all the desired subjects and perform an outer join with the result set retrieved.

I have tested this and it works perfectly. Complete solution(Oracle 18c) with table and Query can be found in DBFIDDLE URL https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df73453d7fa4e0478e74fa509b20a411.

```
  WITH some_data AS ( 
       SELECT 'MATH' AS subj
       FROM dual
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'SCIENCE' AS subj
       FROM dual
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'HISTORY' AS subj
       FROM dual
    )
    SELECT
        nvl(subj,'TOTAL') "Subject",
        nvl(SUM(cnt),0) "Count",
        nvl(SUM(pct),0) AS "%"
    FROM
    (SELECT
        dd,
        COUNT(1) cnt,
        round(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1) ) OVER() * 100,2) AS pct
    FROM
        student p,
        student_subject a
    WHERE
        p.sId = a.sId
        AND student_type IN (
            '1',
            '2'
        )
        AND dd IN (
            'MATH',
            'SCIENCE',
            'HISTORY'
        )
        GROUP BY
        dd
    ORDER BY
        1
    ) tab, some_data
    where tab.dd(+) = some_data.subj
    GROUP BY
        ROLLUP(subj)
    ORDER BY
        1;
```

Comment: Outer join didnt help.

Comment: I have updated the query and solved it now. Refer the DBFIDDLE link for complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use case statement to make it 0, If any of the subject is null then default it to 0. Let me know if you require a query. Am suggesting the logic so that you can try yourself.

Comment: help with this please. I got stuk with case or may be i should say I do not know to use case with outer select in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the list of tables as the `inner view` and use `left join` as follows:

```
SELECT NVL(DD, 'TOTAL') "Subject",
       SUM(CNT) "Count",
       SUM(PCT) AS "%"
FROM (
    SELECT DD,
           COUNT(1) CNT,
           ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(1)) OVER() * 100, 2) AS PCT
    FROM (
        SELECT 'MATH' AS SUB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'SCIENCE' AS SUB FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 'HISTORY' AS SUB FROM DUAL
    ) SUBJECTS
    LEFT JOIN STUDENT_SUBJECT A
    ON SUBJECTS.SUB = A.DD
    LEFT JOIN STUDENT P
    ON P.SID = A.SID
    WHERE STUDENT_TYPE IN (
        '1','2'
    )
    GROUP BY DD
    ORDER BY 1
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(DD)
ORDER BY 1;
```